# Running a `docker` container with `detach=False`

Tags: docker, go

In my Golang program, I am currently spawning a Docker container to perform some work. I chose to use a Docker container here since there are a lot of dependencies and OS-related items that will be much simpler to manage via a packaged container image. I am using the Golang Docker API to manage the containers (`github.com/docker/docker/client`)

One issue I am facing is if the consumer of my Golang program presses `Ctrl-C`, the program quits but the Docker container is still running. This will cause actions to keep continuing even if the consumer believes they have stopped the program.

If the Golang program was instead a bash script, I believe that running `docker run` without the `-d` flag would cause the container to be stopped as soon as this calling parent is stopped. However, in the Golang docker client at the URL provided previously, I don't see an option to do this. There are two parts here: `container_create.go` and `container_start.go`. The structs provided for `container_create` only contain pre-run based configurations (such as ports to expose, etc.), but there is no mention of background or detached modes. `container_start` also does not seem to have any options relevant to this.

Comment: You probably need to trap the interrupt signal and then explicitly stop the container.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the suggestion. Had that in the back of my mind, but was hoping not to go in that direction in case the Go API already had the means to do it.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  I'm more specifically wondering whether it would be helpful to `defer` stopping and deleting the container, which should work even if the Go program is stopped normally.